# What causes these black lines in Hi8 video and how can I get rid of them?

Tags: analog

I've been digitizing some old (late 90s, early 2000s) Hi8 tapes and I've noticed some short black (sometimes white but very rarely) lines that appear randomly in points where the brightness goes from low to high sharply, including the left edge of the frame. Some tapes have no lines and some have many.

[image: a frame from a video with black and white lines]

In 2022, I recorded a video on an old tape. When I played it back afterwards, there were very few black lines. But when I played it back 1 year after I recorded it, there were about as many as there were in recordings from the 2000s.

What causes this and how can I remove these lines from the video?

Comment: Welcome! I never worked with Hi-8 much, but my best guess is the oxide is coming off the tape. I'm guessing that because you said the tape you recorded in 2022 started out with the artifacts and then they got worse. If that's the case, there really isn't much you can do to fix it, just make sure you are storing the tapes in the best conditions possible. But since the artifacts start in a light area, it might be something else that might be correctable. If you have access to another VCR, try a tape in there for comparison.